# Prevent page from loading

Tags: php, html, forms

How can I prevent my PHP form from going to the next step if there are errors? So Basically I have my form named `index.php` and my PHP file named `register.php` which handles the form. How can I have `register.php` send errors to `index.php` and not go to `register.php` if there are errors? So basically I want to pass errors from `register.php` to `index.php` and if there are errors the user doesn't go to `register.php`. I hope this makes sense :)

`register.php`

```
<?php
include '/Users/idrisk/Colourity/s/db.php';

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$pass1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass1']);
$pass2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass2']);

// Verification

if (empty($name) || empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($pass1) || empty($pass2))
    {
    echo "Complete all fields";

    // you can stop it here instead of putting the curly brace ALL the way at the bottom :)

    return;
    }

// Password match

if ($pass1 <> $pass2)
    {
    echo $passmatch = "Passwords don't match";
    }

// Email validation

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
    echo $emailvalid = "Enter a  valid email";
    }

// Password length

if (strlen($pass1) <= 6)
    {
    echo $passlength = "Password must be at least 6 characters long";
    }

// Password numbers

if (!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $pass1))
    {
    echo $passnum = "Password must include at least one number!";
    }

// Password letters

if (!preg_match("#[a-zA-Z]+#", $pass1))
    {
    echo $passletter = "Password must include at least one letter!";
    }



?>
```

And my `index.php`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="register.php">
     Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(!empty($_post['name'])){echo $name;}?>"><br>
     Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(!empty($_post['username'])){echo $username;}?>"><br>
     Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(!empty($_post['email'])){echo $email;}?>"><br>
     Password: <input type="text" name="pass1" value="<?php if(!empty($_post['pass1'])){echo $pass1;}?>"><br>
     Password, again: <input type="text" name="pass2" value="<?php if(!empty($_post['pass2'])){echo $pass2;}?>"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So i want the errors from `register.php` to go to `index.php` And yes I know my code isn't secure. It's just being used as a demo on my computer only.

Comment: All set. I updated. @kimbarcelona

Comment: `$_post` is not `$_POST`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do if this is just a demo, is to have everything all in one page.

Your `index.php` would contain a form that has an `action="index.php"`

```
<?php
include '/Users/idrisk/Colourity/s/db.php';

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_POST["submit"])) {

    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $pass1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass1']);
    $pass2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass2']);



    // Verification

    if (empty($name) || empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($pass1) || empty($pass2))
    {
        echo "Complete all fields";

        // you can stop it here instead of putting the curly brace ALL the way at the bottom :)

        return;
    }

    // Password match

    if ($pass1 <> $pass2)
    {
        echo $passmatch = "Passwords don't match";
    }

    // Email validation

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        echo $emailvalid = "Enter a  valid email";
    }

    // Password length

    if (strlen($pass1) <= 6)
    {
        echo $passlength = "Password must be at least 6 characters long";
    }

    // Password numbers

    if (!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $pass1))
    {
        echo $passnum = "Password must include at least one number!";
    }

    // Password letters

    if (!preg_match("#[a-zA-Z]+#", $pass1))
    {
        echo $passletter = "Password must include at least one letter!";
    }

// check to see if all of the error variable are empty
if(empty($passmatch) && empty($emailvalid) && empty($passlength) && empty($passnum) && empty($passletter)) {
    // everything was empty so we have a good form
    // redirect to another page
    header('Location: example.com/');
}
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
     Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(!empty($_post['name'])){echo $name;}?>"><br>
     Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(!empty($_post['username'])){echo $username;}?>"><br>
     Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(!empty($_post['email'])){echo $email;}?>"><br>
     Password: <input type="text" name="pass1" value="<?php if(!empty($_post['pass1'])){echo $pass1;}?>"><br>
     Password, again: <input type="text" name="pass2" value="<?php if(!empty($_post['pass2'])){echo $pass2;}?>"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also say the form _is_ completed correctly. How would I go to the next page?

Comment: If passmatch emailvalue and the other error checks are all empty your form has been completed successfully you can then redirect after all those checks to your next page.

Comment: Use the PHP header to redirect: header('Location: http://www.example.com/');  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: That then redirects me to the page on load.

Comment: Your redirect must be inside of an if statement that checks all of your error variables, if all of the error variables are empty then redirect, and it must also be at the end of the "submit" if statement.

Comment: Still redirecting when I use `else` once all of the fields have been entered correctly.

Comment: Use this I edited your code and added the check in the right place.  http://pastebin.com/xEkYN0Tz

Comment: I tested this code and it does show the errors, and redirects when the form is good.  The error are above the form, you would have to edit the form itself to have them display beside the form elements.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually posting to `register.php` but to the same page, `index.php`.

That seems the right thing to do because now you can use:

```
include 'register.php';
```

at the top of your script so that the variables are processed in the same page. Then - on a successful submission - you can redirect the visitor to another page where you display your success message.

And if the form contains errors, you can display them in / above / below the form itself.

Comment: That was something I took out by accident. But my question is how do get errors from `register.php` to `index.php`. Since when I submit the errors are displayed on `register.php`

Comment: @user302975 Like I said, post to `index.php` and include `register.php` there.

Comment: But see. Now I get theses errors. `Notice: Undefined index: name in /usr/local/zend/share/UserServer/s/register.php on line 10`. Here's a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/j4aV3aL.png

Comment: It works though. So how would I get rid of the errors?

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways you can do it

1 - there is no need to send the info to another page, when you can handle it on the same page

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];>">
```

in this case you can use

```
if (condition here) { 
// if true //
header('Location: register.php');
}
else {
echo "Error";
}
```

2 - you can set a temporary cookie on register.php too, if there are errors,
so on index.php you can have

like

```
if (error) {
setcookie("Error","Invalid Login",strtotime("+1 minute");
}
```

and on index.php

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["Error"]) {
echo "Invalid Login";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In index.php

Set action attribute value form to register.php.

Then at very top of register.php.

Check if empty field then redirect to index.php with header() function and exit;

---

Example code in register.php if found error.

```
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

hi try this code you need to use session or cookie.

register.php

```
<?php
session_start();

include '/Users/idrisk/Colourity/s/db.php';

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$pass1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass1']);
$pass2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass2']);

$error = array();

// Verification

if (empty($name) || empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($pass1) || empty($pass2))
{
    $empty = "All Fields must be filled up!";
    array_push($error, $empty);
    $_SESSION['error'] = $error;
    header('Location: index.php');
}

// Password match

if ($pass1 <> $pass2)
{
    $passmatch = "Passwords don't match";
    array_push($error, $passmatch);
    $_SESSION['error'] = $error;
}

// Email validation

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    $emailvalid = "Enter a  valid email";
    array_push($error, $emailvalid);
    $_SESSION['error'] = $error;
}

// Password length

if (strlen($pass1) <= 6)
{
    $passlength = "Password must be at least 6 characters long";
    array_push($error, $passlength);
    $_SESSION['error'] = $error;
}

// Password numbers

if (!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $pass1))
{
    $passnum = "Password must include at least one number!";
    array_push($error, $passnum);
    $_SESSION['error'] = $error;
}

// Password letters

if (!preg_match("#[a-zA-Z]+#", $pass1))
{
    $passletter = "Password must include at least one letter!";
    array_push($error, $passletter);
    $_SESSION['error'] = $error;
}

header('Location: index.php');

?>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION["error"]))
{
    foreach($_SESSION["error"] as $error)
    {
        echo "<div>" . $error . "</div>";
    }
}
unset($_SESSION["error"]);
?>
<form method="post" action="register.php">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(!empty($_post['name'])){echo $name;}?>"><br>
Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(!empty($_post['username'])){echo $username;}?>"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php if(!empty($_post['email'])){echo $email;}?>"><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="pass1" value="<?php if(!empty($_post['pass1'])){echo $pass1;}?>"><br>
Password, again: <input type="text" name="pass2" value="<?php if(!empty($_post['pass2'])){echo $pass2;}?>"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I make an error and try like 10 minutes later, I still have the errors show up when I load the page.

Comment: Check your validation.

Comment: or just destroy the whole session by inserting this to the last php line session_destroy();

Comment: weird because it is working on mine just fine. maybe check your included files.

Comment: change this line $name = $_POST['name'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

and get rid of the 

register.php

include '/Users/idrisk/Colourity/s/db.php'; for a moment.